# confuserEx, Clickonce and Icon

Tags: c#, clickonce

I developed my first application in **C#** and are working to create an installation package with **ClicOnce**.
I chose to also use **ConfuserEx** to tarnish my manifests.

I follow the guide
https://confuser.codeplex.com/discussions/428378

After installation, on the Desktop, I find a generic and not my custom icon. The icon that instead is the right one when I install the application without obfuscation.

Does anyone know help me?

Comment: Do you think anyone can see your desktop? Show the problem and if possible with screen shots.

Answer (score 1):

You can still edit the output icon using 'Resource hacker' if it's not a problem for you to go into Google searches